# Need help adding rel to an img tag using js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lightbox

I need help with some JS. I need to add `rel="lightbox"` to the main images of the code below so that these images will open in a lightbox. I grabbed this code from the inspector and this is being generated by a plugin so instead of editing the plugin files I'd like to add the rel code another way. I assume I can add this via JS but nothing I am finding is working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="rsOverflow" style="width: 786px; height: 544px;">
    <div class="rsContainer">
        <div style="z-index:0;" class="rsSlide ">
            <div class="rsContent">
                <img class="rsImg rsMainSlideImage" src="http://166.62.38.87/~saphotonics/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/SA-62H_image1-1024x894.jpg" style="width: 555px; height: 484px; margin-left: 115px; margin-top: 30px;">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div style="z-index:0; display:none; opacity:0;" class="rsSlide ">
            <div class="rsContent">
                <img class="rsImg rsMainSlideImage" src="http://166.62.38.87/~saphotonics/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/SA-62H_image2-1008x1024.jpg" style="width: 477px; height: 484px; margin-left: 154px; margin-top: 30px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsFullscreenBtn">
        <div class="rsFullscreenIcn"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What plugin are you using? They may have a template you can override or hook into an `add_filter` function.

Comment: I'm using RoyalSlider. I asked their support and all they said is that I'd need to use a 3rd party lightbox plugin but they give no instructions on how to implement it unfortunately.

Comment: I looked at their site - there's a section called Slide Markup Editor: https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img.rsImg')

for(let img of imgs){
  img.setAttribute('rel', 'lightbox');
}
```

The code is not tested, but I'm sure it'll guide you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of the images you want are tagged with the class "rsImg".
If this is the case, you can select all images with that class and add the "rel" attribute to them...

```
document.querySelectorAll('img.rsImg') // selects all "img" tags that have class "rsImg"
        .forEach(                      // for each of the things selected, run the code here
                 n => n.setAttribute('rel', 'lightbox')
                )
```

The following snippet runs that code, using your html from the question (with the images changed to placeholders) -- after it runs you can use your browser to inspect the element(s) and see that the `rel` attribute is added to each `img`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img.rsImg').forEach(n => n.setAttribute('rel', 'lightbox'))
```

```html
<div class="rsOverflow" style="width: 786px; height: 544px;">
    <div class="rsContainer">
        <div style="z-index:0;" class="rsSlide ">
            <div class="rsContent">
                <img class="rsImg rsMainSlideImage" src="//www.fillmurray.com/1024/894" style="width: 555px; height: 484px; margin-left: 115px; margin-top: 30px;">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div style="z-index:0; display:none; opacity:0;" class="rsSlide ">
            <div class="rsContent">
                <img class="rsImg rsMainSlideImage"
                     src=" //www.fillmurray.com/1008/1024"
                     style="width: 477px; height: 484px; margin-left: 154px; margin-top: 30px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rsFullscreenBtn">
        <div class="rsFullscreenIcn"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```